# How can you display your logs when testing android apps on real devices?

Tags: android-studio, logging

So I am developing my first app with Android Studio, it's a Shopping app and everything seems to work just fine when I try it out on the built-in Emulator (Android 9). However, when I connect my Smartphone (same Android version), I won't get pass my Login screen. Currently the data is stored through SQLite, which may cause issues.
I'd really like to look up what's the exact problem, but there is no Log feed showing up in Android Studios.

Are there any settings that provide the same Logs as if I was running it on an Emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have selected right device i.e there is a dropdown option for devices in logcat check that and choose your device because it will be set to the previous device by default

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you would want to use logcat?You can debug phone issues in it also, just select your phone in the options. I have two external phones I test on, logcat shows those phones.

[image]